# ios sdk rename file name extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, file-rename, batch-rename

Objective-C:
I want to rename all files in the documents folder.
For all files with extensions .xyz1, I want to change to .gif
loop through and change:
  file1.xyz1, file44.xyz1, file789.xyz1 should all become file1.gif, file44.gif, file789.gif

Comment: On Stack overflow you don't ask for someone to write code for you. You instead try to make it yourself and the questions here ask why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `Finder` and then re-add to your project.
For mass rename files in `Finder` choose they and right-clik. In menu drop-down menu choose `rename objects()` and set the rules for rename.